# Is PhP 7.2 Compatible with uubuntu 22.04xx

Tags: system-installation

I need to upgrade to ubuntu 22.04xx for laravel project, but our current php 7.2 will not have problem? Isn't it?

Comment: PHP 7.2 will be upgraded to version 8.1, same as other packages.